# PostgreSQL recursive sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `Project` in which a parent-child relationship is stored. 
An entry in the `parentprojectid` column implies that the respective project instance is a child. 
The columns of the table are as follows:

```
projectid, parentprojectid
```

When I run a SELECT query on this table, the resulting data should consist of every parent followed by all of its children (and the children of its children, if applicable). How do I achieve this?

Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
projectid  parentprojid  
proj1      null  
proj11     proj1  
proj12     proj1  
proj121    proj12  
proj2      null  
proj3      null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [recursive common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), combine all parents into array and then sort by resulting array:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select t.projectid, t.parentprojid, array[t.projectid::text] as path
    from Table1 as t
    where t.parentprojid is null
    union all
    select t.projectid, t.parentprojid, c.path || t.projectid::text
    from Table1 as t
        inner join cte as c on c.projectid = t.parentprojid
)
select projectid, parentprojid
from cte
order by path
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d5e9f/5)</kbd>**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well as far as I see, `projectid` is already text (varchar actually)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, I've tried to find numeric `id` for some time before realized that this `name` is `id`:)

Comment: What is the purpose behind converting the path column to an array, when the query runs fine even without conversion to array?

Comment: well you can convert it to string, but you have to carefully choose separator, like `c.path || '->' || t.projectid::text`. Imagine you have two parents - `'A'` and `'AA'` and children `'A' -> 'AA1'` and `'AA' -> 'A1'`. IF you concatenate it to string without separators, you'll receive two of `'AAA1'`. Using array helps not to think about what separator you'll use.

Comment: Thanks working fine :) Got to learn about the recursive concepts